draw I2C timming with proper package
I would like to draw a I2C timming sequence diagram like below:

I searched and found a timming package but still not as expected:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}[2014/10/29]
\usetikztiminglibrary[rising arrows]{clockarrows}
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand{\busref}{som}{\texttt{%
#3%
\IfValueTF{#2}{[#2]}{}%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\#}{}%
}}
   \begin{tikztimingtable}[
scale=2,
      timing/d/background/.style={fill=gray!20},
      timing/wscale=2.0,
      timing/lslope=0.2,
     ]
     SDA & H L D{d6} D{d5} D{d4} D{d3} D{d2} D{d1} D{d0} H L D{d7} D L L H \\
     SCL & H h L 24{c} HH \\
         & 17L \\
   \extracode
     \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
       \begin{scope}[semitransparent,semithick]
         \vertlines[red]{2.25,5,17,28.5}
       \end{scope}
     \end{pgfonlayer}
     \begin{scope}[font=\small]
       \def\dy{-4.5}
       [font=\sffamily\Large,shift={(0,-0.5)},anchor=east]
       \draw[-latex] (-3,-1.5) -- (-3,1.5) node[pos=.5,sloped,above] {Logic Level};
       \node[anchor=center] at (2.25, \dy) {start};
       \node[anchor=center] at (10.25, \dy) {I2C address};              
       \node[anchor=center] at (22.25, \dy) {ACK};              
       \node[anchor=center] at (25.25, \dy) {Data};              
       \node[anchor=center] at (28.5, \dy) {End};              
     \end{scope}
   \end{tikztimingtable}%
\end{document}


Current output:

Still 2 items need help:

The red colored line not marked.
The data section skip symbol not implemented.


You supply some code that creates half a diagram. You can not expect people to just finish your work. You need to write what is not as expected and what is causing you problems.

it's not clear what about the first image you're trying to copy since you've apparently made intentional changes to the code, presumably because you want e.g. arrows and different labels, which is fine, but how are we to know what further change you're not getting? or what different change you wanted some part of your code to effect?

have you looked at the package documentation? it looks pretty straightforward to add things like arrows etc.

which red line? do you mean something in black right now should be red? or do you mean the legend at the top left?

your code doesn't produce the output you show. when I compile it, I have arrows missing from your image.

The manual provides examples of how to do most of the things you want and you've already started to use this for some of your desiderata. Your output suggests you also discovered how to remove the arrows on the timings, though your code did not produce that result for me, so I reimplemented that.
Of the remaining items on your list, the manual provides examples of how to colour the lines, which may or may not be the coloured line you want. If you want the legend instead, you should be able to adapt the code below which focuses on drawing the discontinuity. This is for two reasons. First, the site is supposed to work according to a one-question-per-question format. Second, unlike the examples provided for colouring lines, I could not find an example of the discontinuity in the docs, so it seems most helpful to answer that question.
Since I couldn't see any obvious out-of-the-box option, I did this using two more generic features:

timing/after table is an 'action' you can redefine to do what you please within the tikzpicture. This means you have access to the nodes and coordinates and can also use the internal coordinate system. This makes it easier to place arbitrary content.
The names of the various nodes, as explained in the helpful illustration in figure 2.2 of the manual.

I still had to experiment a bit to figure out how this worked, but once you understand how to redefine an 'action' and figure out a couple of the node names, things get much easier and feel like regular tikz.
    timing/after table/.code={%

The introduction to section 3 on page 28 is key.
      \path (row2.south) ++(0pt,-0.25) coordinate (b);

The 'rows' have names such as row1, row2 and so on. These are just regular nodes, so they have regular anchors. b is just a convenience coordinate.
      \draw [double,] (row1.north) ++(5.5,0.25) coordinate (a) ++(1.5pt,0pt) [bend right] to ([xshift=-1.5pt]a |- row1.south) [bend left] to ([xshift=1.5pt]a |- row2.north) [bend right] to ([xshift=-1.5pt]b -| a)  ;

A bit fiddly and doubtless you'll want to tweak it, but this is just drawing a regular path with regular syntax. The only non-standard items are the row<n> nodes and, I think, the coordinates which may be internal to the diagram (but I'm not certain of this - I just played around with it).
    },

That's really all there is to it, so it doesn't look much. It just takes a bit of reading the docs and a little messing around to get the hang of where things are.

I wasn't really sure where it was meant to be in your diagram, but you can easily move it by adjusting the starting coordinate.
Complete code:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
% addaswyd o gwestion lucky1928: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/724721/
\usepackage{tikz-timing}%[2014/10/29]
\usetikztiminglibrary[]{clockarrows}
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand{\busref}{som}{\texttt{%
    #3%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{[#2]}{}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\#}{}%
}}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[
    scale=2,
    timing/d/background/.style={fill=gray!20},
    timing/wscale=2.0,
    timing/lslope=0.2,
    timing/after table/.code={% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724803/
      \path (row2.south) ++(0pt,-0.25) coordinate (b);
      \draw [double,] (row1.north) ++(5.5,0.25) coordinate (a) ++(1.5pt,0pt) [bend right] to ([xshift=-1.5pt]a |- row1.south) [bend left] to ([xshift=1.5pt]a |- row2.north) [bend right] to ([xshift=-1.5pt]b -| a)  ;
    },
  ]
  SDA & H L D{d6} D{d5} D{d4} D{d3} D{d2} D{d1} D{d0} H L D{d7} D L L H \\
  SCL & H h L 24{c} HH \\
      & 17L \\
      \extracode
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \begin{scope}[semitransparent,semithick]
          \vertlines[red]{2.25,5,17,28.5}
        \end{scope}
      \end{pgfonlayer}
      \begin{scope}[font=\small]
        \def\dy{-4.5}
        % [font=\sffamily\Large,shift={(0,-0.5)},anchor=east]
        \draw[-latex] (-3,-1.5) -- (-3,1.5) node[pos=.5,sloped,above] {Logic Level};
        \node[anchor=center] at (2.25, \dy) {start};
        \node[anchor=center] at (10.25, \dy) {I2C address};
        \node[anchor=center] at (22.25, \dy) {ACK};
        \node[anchor=center] at (25.25, \dy) {Data};
        \node[anchor=center] at (28.5, \dy) {End};
      \end{scope}
\end{tikztimingtable}%
\end{document}

